# Approaches to Solving Quadratic Diophantine Equations of the Form $x^2 + y^2 = k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

I am exploring the solutions of quadratic Diophantine equations in the following form:

$$
x_1^2 + y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2 = \dots = x_n^2 + y_n^2 = k,
$$

where $x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n, k \in \mathbb{N}$. For the similar case of $x_1^2 - y_1^2 = x_2^2 - y_2^2 = \dots = x_n^2 - y_n^2 = k$, it's relatively straightforward to express each term as $(x_i - y_i)(x_i + y_i) = k$ and find pairs $(x_i, y_i)$ from the permutations of $k$'s prime multipliers, determining $n$ in the process. However, I am struggling to find a similar approach for the sum case.

I have searched for similar problems but haven't found much that deals with this specific form. Are there known methods or approaches to tackle this kind of problem? Any pointers towards relevant literature or examples would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$; the norm of the Gaussion integer $a+bi$. Therefore, this is just the problem of factoring $k$ in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: You want   Theorem 65  on page 80 of Dickson(1929) Introduction to the Theory of Numbers. To get a large number of pairs  let $k$  be the product of consecutive primes $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$   so the prime factors will be chosen from $5, 13, 17, 29,...$   Dickson, scanned  https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n89/mode/2up

Comment: you need to know this: given a number $m = 2^{a_2} \cdot 3^{a_3} \cdot 5^{a_5} \cdots$   where only a finite number of the exponents $a_j$   are nonzero,  the number of divisors of $m$  is $(a_2 + 1)(a_3 + 1 ) (a_5 +1) \cdots,$   where only a finite number of the $a_p + 1 $ are larger than $1$

Comment: We can find a solution for any integer $n$ for which $k$ satisfies Will's condition.
For instance, the rational solution of $x^2+y^2=5$ is given $(x,y)=(\frac{-1+k^2-4k}{1+k^2}, \frac{2(-1+k^2+k)}{1+k^2})$.
For $k=1,3,5$, we get $2^2+1^2=(\frac{2}{5})^2+(\frac{11}{5})^2=(\frac{2}{13})^2+(\frac{29}{13})^2=5$.
Hence, we get $130^2+65^2=26^2+143^2=10^2+145^2=5 \cdot 65^2$.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 2):

There is an Identity of degree four & is given below:

$(4m^4-n^4)^2+(4m^2n^2)^2$=

$(8m^3n-4mn^3)^2+(4m^4-8m^2n^2+n^4)^2$=

=$(p^2+q^2)$=$(r^2+s^2)$=$(4m^4+n^4)^2$

where:

$p=(n^2+2mn)(2m^2-2mn+n^2)$

$q=(2m^2+2mn)(2m^2-2mn+n^2)$

$r=(n^2-2mn)(2m^2+2mn+n^2)$

$s=(2m^2-2mn)(2m^2+2mn+n^2)$

for, $(m,n)=(2,1)$ we get:

$65^2=63^2+16^2=56^2+33^2=25^2+60^2=39^2+52^2$

Comment: As mathematician "Seiji Tomita" commented there are chains of solutions for different integers, (m)=n(k^2). For example for n=1 & k=1105 we have 13 pairs in a chain & is given here. 
1105^2=(700,855)^2=(744,817)^2=(47,1104)^2=(105,1100)^2=(169,1092)^2=(264,1073)^2=
(272,1071)^2=(425,1020)^2=(468,1001)^2=(520,975)^2=(561,952)^2=(576,943)^2=(663,884)^2. And this chain also can be parameterized.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- $(1)$ First at all, the integer $k$ must be of the form $k=\prod p_i^{n_i}q_j^{2n_j}$ where the primes $p_i$ are conguent to $1$ modulo $4$ and the primes $q_j$ are conguent to $-1$ (or equivalently to $3$) modulo $4$. Otherwise $k$ cannot be a sum of two squares.

$(2)$ Next, the general solution of the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$ is known to be given by the parameterization
$$2x=rX+sY\\2y=rY-sX\\2z=rX-sY\\2w=rY+sX$$ where $r,s$ are arbitrary integers and $X,Y$ are two parameters (it is easy to prove this general solution because we have clearly an identity directly verifiable.

$(3)$ What remains depends on $n$: the larger $n$ is, the greater the difficulty will be in conditioning the step $(2)$ to your purpose.